# How to do product construction with 2 DFA which has dead state

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I have been trying to do a product construction(intersection) with 2 DFA which has dead states, but I'm stuck at the transition table with a confusion that,what should I do with dead state. Should I also combine the dead state with other states?

Answer (score 2):

The product construction works for *any* two DFAs. There is nothing special you need to do. The resulting automaton would have many dead states and so won't be minimal, but that doesn't affect its correctness.

Comment: SO you are saying that if I have 3 states A, B and C(dead state) for one dfa and p, q and r states for the other, then when I combine these states I can have C(Deadstate) p, C(Deadstate) q and C(Deadstate) r ??

Comment: You can have as many dead states as you wish. The definition of DFA nowhere states that you are only allowed to have at most one dead state.